# Why is my function editing an variable i didnt specify?

Tags: python, function, global-variables

```
print(generated)
grid = Main(generated,boxes)
print("gnen")
print(generated)
print("grid")
print(grid)
```

For context: this is a sudoku generator and Main() solves a sudoku and returns a solved sudoku. However generated is edited.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: You are asking us why `Main()` is doing something unexpected. But if you want help with the code, *you need to show us the code*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are mutating the `generated` in the function you shouldn't do that add this line at the top of the file

```py
import copy
```

and then edit the function `Main` as this

```py
def Main(your_variable_name_here, your_variable_name_here2):
    your_variable_name_here_ = copy.deepcopy(your_variable_name_here)
```

change this across all your `Main` function i.e after editing the function use `your_variable_name_here_` and not `your_variable_name_here`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: You sir are my hero thank you

Comment: @Iwant if you find my answer helpful you can click on the checkmark to accept it